# java swing compiler for programming on android tablet

Tags: android, swing, java

Any IDE is available for  android tablet to run the java swing?
Currently i am using `Android Java Editor` IDE for Programming in android.
But it's not compile the swing programs.
Which IDE is compile the swing programs?
And also i wonder to know how android apps compile and  run the java files without jdk.

Comment: http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/developer/15-apps-for-programming-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

Swing isn't available on Android. Android uses Java as the programming language but doesn't include the complete framework as the JDK does.

Swing is a component in Java SE. To see what classes are included in the Android SDK you can lookup the api documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

The compiled java-classes for Android don't run on the normal JVM but on the Dalvik VM which was built specifically for Android.

Comment: i am asking to do programming in android tablet.

Comment: Same goes for tablets. If you want to make Apps for android (phone or tablet, doesn't matter) you have to use the Android SDK. You can read how you can build your own apps on http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: i dont want  to make apps for android. i want to do run java programs in android mobile or tablet.

Comment: That's not possible. There is no Java Runtime for Android. Just the Dalvik VM.

Comment: check this [link](http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/developer/15-apps-for-programming-on-android/)

Comment: I don't see what that link has to do with it, but running Swing applications on Android is simply not possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30477/discussion-between-karthi-and-ozzie)

Answer (score 1):

> i wonder to know how android apps run the java files without jdk'

*Instead of `JVM` android uses `DVM(DALVIK VIRTUAL MACHINE)`is Register Architecture, designed to run on low memory, uses its own byte code and runs .Dex file (`Dalvik Executable File`),
Java  source code is compiled by the Java compiler into .class files. Then the dx (dexer) tool, part of the Android SDK processes the .class files into a proprietary file format called DEX that contains Dalvik bytecode.*